# Texture Coordinate overlays another texture on my existing texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor

I'm fairly new at Blender so there are so many ways I could be doing this wrong. Right now I'm working on a cobbled street but when I try to scale it using a mapping and texture coordinate node it's almost like the same texture is overlayed on top in rendered view.

Here is my node setup:

[image: Here is my node setup]

And this is what it looks like rendered:
[image: Here is what it looks like rendered]

Also, when I add the displacement modifier after subdividing it, the new geometry changes to the weird texture that the texture coordinate made as opposed to the scaled texture.

Shown here:[image: Shown here]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What I would say from what I understand:

You need to plug the *Texture Coordinate* > *Mapping* chain into the *Vector* of the *Image Texture* of your *Bump*, exactly like what you've done for the *Image Texture* of your *Diffuse*, otherwise he doesn't know how to project this *Bump* information on your floor.

[image]

Now you say that you've added a *Displace* modifier. I'm not sure why, as your the Bump method is a way to fake relief within a low-poly mesh without any additional subdivision.

If you choose to use a *Displace* modifier you should not use a *Bump* node, just unwrap your mesh (for example in *Top Ortho* view make a *Project From View* unwrap), use *UV* as the output of your *Texture Coordinate* so that he knows that he must use the UV you've just created, and mix a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy*, with your Specularity image as the factor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, the displacement mod is definitely what is causing the problem. If you look at rendered/material vs. solid, the displacement UV is making the texture (brick) look huge, while in render, the texture is much smaller.

I would fix this by removing the displacement, subdividing the plane and doing like said in the previous answer, or by subdividing, and creating a realistic-looking displace using the roughness texture (usually available with the texture, or if not, then able to be created with crazybump), then to save memory, bake it to a normal map.